# Foreach loop in Preamble

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, loops

I am familiar with the `\foreach` loop in the TikZ pakage. Is there an analogous loop I can use in my preamble? I like to use `\M`, `\A`, `\I`, and other commands as shorthand for matrices. So instead of writing

```
\renewcommand\S{\mathbf S}    
\newcommand\V{\mathcal V}
\newcommand\E{\mathcal E}
\newcommand\M{\mathbf M}
\newcommand\A{\mathbf A}
\newcommand\z{\mathbf z}
\newcommand\x{\mathbf x}
\newcommand\B{\mathbf B}
\newcommand\I{\mathbf I}
\newcommand\J{\mathbf J}
\newcommand\X{\mathbf X}
\newcommand\Q{\mathbf Q}
```

Can I do something to the effect of

```
\foreach \x in {S, V, E, M, A, z, x, B, I, J, X, Q}{
    \let\x\relax
    \newcommand \\x {\mathbf \x}
 }
```

I'm asking just to make my preamble look a bit cleaner. I'm open to other suggestions too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is a way to use a for loop in LaTeX which doesn't require any packages:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\@for\cs:={S,V,E,M,A,z,x,B,I,J,X,Q}\do{
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname my\cs\endcsname{}% check whether the command is already defined
  \expandafter\edef\csname my\cs\endcsname{\noexpand\mathbf{\cs}}% define it expanding \cs
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\myS$
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would one go about creating a similar loop to define multiple `\newtheorem` envirnoments?

Comment: I'd probably go a similar way to daleif's. Create a command which takes the theorem-name as an argument and defines it. Then call that command in a `\@for`-loop with `\expandafter\MyNewTheorem\expandafter{\cs}`.

Comment: @LukeCollins You could as well use your `\@for`-loop with `\@for\cs:={{name1}{description1},{name2}{description2}}\do{\expandafter\newtheorem\cs}`. But for that, I think this is obfuscating and `\newtheorem{name1}{description1}\newtheorem{name2}{description2}` is better.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Skillmon, but using `etoolbox` for simpler code. I also recommend prefixing the macros to avoid unintentionally overwriting build in macros.

This can easily be adapted to also make others.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,bm}
\newcommand\Maker[1]{
  \ifcsundef{bf#1}{
    \csdef{bf#1}{\bm{#1}}
  }{
    \typeout{Cannot make \string\bf#1, already exists, ignoring}
  }
}
\forcsvlist\Maker{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}
\forcsvlist\Maker{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}

\begin{document}

\[
\bfa
\]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want clean syntax, `expl3` is for you.

```
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn % access the programmer's level

\clist_map_inline:nn
 { S, V, E, M, A, z, x, B, I, J, X, Q }
 {
  \cs_new_protected:cpn {b#1} { \mathbf{#1} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This will define `\bS`, `\bV` and so on. Avoid redefining commands such as `\S`. If you want to be on the risky side, use `\cs_set_protected:cpn` instead of `\cs_new_protected:cpn`, but then blame yourself if something goes wrong.